# 'React/RCTImageLoader.h' file not found at RNScreens

Tags: xcode, react-native

I'm building a React native app on Xcode 12.5 and getting the following error: 'React/RCTImageLoader.h' file not found at RNScreens.
I tried with different react-native-screens versions but still getting the same error

[image]

My package.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "^0.1.0-rc.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^6.0.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^6.0.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.9.10",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.3.15",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.0-next.13",
    "@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input": "^1.3.11",
    "appcenter-cli": "^2.7.4",
    "currency-formatter": "^1.5.5",
    "native-base": "^2.13.4",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.60.2",
    "react-native-barcode-builder": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-code-push": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-easy-toast": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.3.9",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-listener": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.26.1",
    "react-native-maps-directions": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.7.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.5.0",
    "react-native-numeric-input": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.6.4",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.8.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^6.3.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-progress-steps": "^1.3.4",
    "react-native-qrcode": "^0.2.7",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^5.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-render-html": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.15.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-share": "^6.0.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-spinkit": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.5.3",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.16.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.3.1",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
    "react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^3.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^5.0.0",
    "reactotron-redux": "^3.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "thunk": "0.0.1",
    "urijs": "^1.19.1",
    "url-search-params-polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "validate.js": "^0.13.1"
  }
```

I need help with this problem. Thanks very much !!!

Comment: clean your build folder, pod install in IOS and then try again

Comment: thanks for your recommend but I tried but still get the same error

Comment: Downgrade react-native-screens version to 1.0.0-alpha.23 fixed my problem